# customize login error message

Tags: users

I'm using [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega)'s sub-theme 'creativpink' and [ajax_register module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_register).

When user enters wrong user name or wrong password I want show *'The password entered is wrong. Please retry.' instead of Drupal's default error *'Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?'*.

I've tried with following code in my sub-theme's template.php file :

```
function _custom_validation(&$form, &$form_state){
  $query = db_select('users', 'u');
  $query->fields('u', array('name'));
  $query->condition('u.name', $form_state['values']['name'], '=');
  $result = $query->execute();
  $name = $result->fetchField();
  if(empty($name)){
    form_set_error('user_name', t('The password entered is wrong. Please retry.'));
  }
}
```

After saving file I entered wrong user name and password. The error message showed both default text and my custom text.

- Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?
- The password entered is wrong. Please retry.

But I want to show only my custom error message. How to do this?

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/comment/28464#comment-28464 please check this comment to unset a message

Answer (score 1):

You can use function [form_get_errors](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_get_errors/7.x) and function [form_clear_error](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_clear_error/7.x)

```
function _custom_validation($form,$form_state){
  $errors = form_get_errors();
  if(!empty($errors)){
    $string_error = $errors['name'];
    if (strpos($string_error, 'unrecognized username or password') !== FALSE) {
      form_clear_error();
      form_set_error('name','The password entered is wrong. Please retry.');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error messages thrown by Drupal core user module are defined in

```
function user_login_final_validate()
```

This can be overridden in any of your own module/theme by calling the form_alter function and replace user_login_final_validate() with your own validator.

Example below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login':
    case 'user_login_block':
      $user_login_final_validate_index = array_search('user_login_final_validate', $form['#validate']);
      if ($user_login_final_validate_index >= 0) {
        $form['#validate'][$user_login_final_validate_index] = 'your_custom_final_validate';
  }
    break;
  }
}

function your_custom_final_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  /* Copy the code from user.module and change to your own message */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the two methods outlined here: http://www.bluespark.com/blog/youre-doing-it-wrong-dont-hack-drupal-core-change-text

Answer (score 0):

You could use the String Overrides module.  According to the project page, the module "Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site."

I've used it before.  It is quite easy to configure and works like a charm.

https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides